# When generating a signed url via getSignedUrl with Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Storage, why cant I upload a file to my bucket?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, axios, google-cloud-storage

Hello and thank you so much for reading.

I am trying to create a mechanism whereby my client code can use a signed URL sent from my server to upload a webm file. Everything works as expected until my client code fires the API call to upload the file. I am receiving a 403 error:

> Error uploading file: .... SignatureDoesNotMatch .... The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.

The url is created and sent to the client without any manipulation. Why would this happen? See below for all the code examples involved in the project.

```
// Server Side / node.js / server.js / localhost:4000

import {Storage} from '@google-cloud/storage';

...

const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: 'my_project_id',
  credentials: {
    client_email: 'my_client_email',
    private_key: 'my_private_key',
  }
});

...

const expires = Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 1000; // 1 hour

const options = {
  version: 'v4',
  action: 'write',
  expires,
  contentType: 'video/webm',
};
    
// Get a v4 signed URL for uploading file
const signedUrlData = await storage
  .bucket('my_bucket')
  .file('my_video.webm')
  .getSignedUrl(options);

const [url] = signedUrlData;

return url; // provides the url correctly from @google-cloud/storage

...
```

---

```
// Client Side / react.js / upload.jsx / localhost:3000

...

// call my server api to generate the signedUrl and set as a variable called "uploadDataUrl"
const {data: result} = await axios({
  method: 'PUT',
  url: uploadDataUrl,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'video/webm',
  },
  data: videoUrl, // url of my blob example: blob:http://localhost:3000/b04758435433-h637-892l-0165-bcuis7893mcd
});

...
```

---

```
...

// 403 Error uploading file - See below:
<Code>
  SignatureDoesNotMatch
</Code>
<Message>
  The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.
</Message>

...
```

---

```
// CORS Data / .json / cors.json
[
  {
    "origin": [
      "http://localhost:3000",
      "http://localhost:4000"
    ],
    "responseHeader": [
      "Content-Type",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
    ],
    "method": [
      "PUT",
      "POST",
      "GET",
      "DELETE",
      "OPTIONS"
    ],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

Comment: FYI for the above question, I also have tried this as a vanilla xhr request, a form request, and other methods. Mostly the question here is around why the url isnt changed, and I still get the "403 SignatureDoesNotMatch" error.

Answer (score 1):

So... I found the issue!!! It sounds like the keys information used to create an authentication to create a signedUrl was incorrect.

That being said, not sure why the url was successfully created when the authentication was incorrect....??

I think google maybe needs to solve this issue as, it is very misleading to get the error after creating the signed URL and using it in an API request, etc.

Referring to this bit by the way:

```
const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: 'my_project_id',
  credentials: {
    client_email: 'my_client_email',
    private_key: 'my_private_key',
  }
});
```

Thanks all!

Comment: The authorization is performed at the time you use the signed URL. The signing process does not validate authorization because credentials are used to generate the signature and network traffic to the cloud is not required (there is an exception with the SignBlob API). Similar to signing a JWT - everything is done locally. Even if Google verified the generated URL, it could still fail later for many reasons (bucket no longer exists, account suspended, etc).